# shortcut ctrl-q not handled in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

why this code not show me messagebox with "ctrl-q pressed" message when i press ctrl-q in win32?

```
        case WM_CHAR:
            switch(wParam) {
                case 'q':
                    if(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0)
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"ctrl-q pressed", L"caption", MB_OK);
                    else 
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"q pressed", L"caption", MB_OK);
                    break;
            }
            return 0;
```

Comment: Because when you hold down ctrl and hit Q the WM_CHAR doesn't get `Q`.

Comment: @MarkRansom So what does it get?

Comment: It gets control-q. I didn't want to say without a reference to the exact hex value, but I'm on my phone.

Comment: @MarkRansom can you show me a simple example? Later with your pc or laptop

Comment: @mehranvakili why not just test it for yourself and see exactly what it does get? That would be faster than waiting on someone else.

Comment: Ctrl-A will give you 0x1, Ctrl-B gives 0x2, etc...

Comment: @JonathanPotter not all CTRL sequences generate WM_CHAR messages at all. Only those that can be translated into ASCII control characters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In a quick test, Ctrl-A through Ctrl-Z all generate `WM_CHAR` messages with `wParam` 0x1 through 0x1a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample to test, the code is as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR szBuffer[1024];
    ZeroMemory(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer));
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        TCHAR tc = TCHAR(wParam);
        sprintf(szBuffer, "key char = %c\n", tc);
        OutputDebugString(szBuffer);
        sprintf(szBuffer, "key char(hex) = %x\n", tc);
        OutputDebugString(szBuffer);
        return 0;
    }

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When I press <kbd>Q</kbd>, it will output in the console:

> key char = q
>
> key char(hex) = 71

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>, it will output:

> key char =   (It cannot be displayed normally here, anyway it is a character)
>
> key char(hex) = 11

So when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>, `WM_CHAR` will not get `Q`.

If you want to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>, you can try the following code:

```
case WM_CHAR:
{
    if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000 && GetKeyState('Q') & 0x8000)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"ctrl-q pressed", L"caption", MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`WM_CHAR` carries *translated* key codes, generated by `TranslateMessage()` when processing `WM_KEYDOWN` messages. Per MSDN's documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input#character-messages

> Some CTRL key combinations are translated into ASCII control characters. For example, CTRL+A is translated to the ASCII ctrl-A (SOH) character (ASCII value 0x01).

And also:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-keyboard-input

> A window procedure receives a character message when the TranslateMessage function translates a virtual-key code corresponding to a character key. The character messages are  WM_CHAR, WM_DEADCHAR, WM_SYSCHAR, and WM_SYSDEADCHAR. A typical window procedure ignores all character messages except WM_CHAR. **The TranslateMessage function generates a WM_CHAR message when the user presses any of the following keys**:
>
> - **Any character key**
> - BACKSPACE
> - ENTER (carriage return)
> - ESC
> - SHIFT+ENTER (linefeed)
> - TAB

So, in this case, <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> will generate a `WM_CHAR` message with its `wParam` set to `0x01..0x1A`.

Comment: You want the *synchronous* key state, so [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) instead of `GetAsyncKeyState`.